# mv: cannot stat 'filename_1_2_3': No such file or directory

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, mv

I wanted to move large amount of files from many directories which are under the parent directory in who I'm positioned.

I used following command with backticks:

```
mv -t directory1/directory2/directory3/ `ls -R | grep _2_3`
```

So I wanted to move the source of command in backticks to the destination directory which is 'directory3' which are find Recursively under my current directory ( parent one )

Is there any solution to do this with the current command? And what does this error mean exactly?

Comment: If you tried `ls -R | grep _2_3 | less` you would see what your command produces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will notice that `ls -R` outputs *filenames*.  That is, it does not output *pathnames*.  Therefore, if a file that contains the string `_2_3` in its name is found in one of your subdirectories, there is no information about *where* that file is found in the output of `ls -R` (on the same line as the filename).  This makes your command fail (the filename is not found in the current directory).  It would also fail for any file that contains a space, tab or newline in its name, and would potentially also produce strange results if any filename contained filename globbing characters.

Instead, assuming you'd want to move files whose filenames *end* in `_2_3` to a directory `/directory1/directory2/directory3` (and that this directory is not a subdirectory of the current directory), then

```
find . -type f -name '*_2_3' -exec mv -t /directory1/directory2/directory3 {} +
```

would do that. This would find the pathnames of all regular files (not directories or named pipes, or symbolic links etc.) whose names end with `_2_3` anywhere in or under the current directory, and would execute `mv -t /directory1/directory2/directory3` with as many of these pathnames as possible in batches.

In the `bash` shell, you could possibly also do

```
shopt -s globstar
mv -t /directory1/directory2/directory3 -- **/*_2_3
```

unless the pattern expands to many thousands of names.  The `globstar` shell option in `bash` enables the `**` globbing pattern. It works like `*` but will match *across* `/` in pathnames.  It would therefore find all names matching `*_2_3` anywhere in or below the current directory. Note that this command does not care what *type* of name is matched, and might match directory names too, for example (but so would your `ls -R` approach do).

In the `zsh` shell, you could be more precise with the matching:

```
mv -t /directory1/directory2/directory3 -- **/*_2_3(.)
```

The `(.)` modifies the behaviour of the preceding pattern to only match regular files. The `**` pattern is enabled by default in `zsh`.

If you wish to find files whose names *contain* `_2_3`, then simply change the `*_2_3` bit of the filename pattern in the above commands to `*_2_3*`.

Answer (score 0):

The important part of the message is: `No such file or directory`. `ls -R` doesn't include the filepath. 
So `mv` has just the filename, but cannot find it, because the path to it is missing.

Do this instead:

```
$ find . -name '*_2_3*' -exec mv -t directory1/directory2/directory3/ {} +
```

Note that the `-exec … {} +` action for `find` is POSIX-compliant,
but `mv -t` is not.